# UWP: File.ReadAllBytes from file in Assets folder

Tags: windows-mobile, win-universal-app, assets, filepath

How can I use `File.ReadAllBytes()`to read a file from the `Assets` folder into a `byte[]`? Therefore I need a filepath. I tried with `ms-appx-web:///Assets/test.jpg`, but that didn't worked. `File.Exists()` return false.

How do I get the absolute path to the assets folder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This fragment shoud do,

```
string fname = @"Assets\test.jpg";
StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(fname);
if(File.Exists(file.Path))
{
    var contents = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);
}
```

Comment: Will the file be read two times? How can `File.Exists()` be used in this case?